# using jQuery, I need to capture var info based on dropdown - id equals var name

Tags: javascript, variables, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu

not sure if I need to use id to accomplish this task

```
<select id="selectedCity" data-native-menu="false" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
  <option value="#">-- Select City --</option>
  <option id="Atla" value="#tiera">Atlanta</option>
  <option id="Aust" value="#tierc">Austin</option>
  <option id="Balt" value="#tiera">Baltimore</option>
  <option id="Bost" value="#tierb">Boston</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to capture the var info below but I need it to match the City the user has selected via dropdown, I then need the var info to fill all p tages on the same page with the selected var info.

```
  var Atla = "info on Atlanta"
  var Aust = "info on Austin"
  var Balt = "info on Baltimore"
  var Bost = "info on Boston"

if id Atla = var Atla
    $("p").text(Atla);

else if id Aust = var Atla
    $("p").text(Aust);

else if...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably easier to make an object which contains the captions, then make each `option` have a custom data-* attribute with the appropriate key:

New options:

```
<select id="selectedCity" data-native-menu="false" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
  <option value="#">-- Select City --</option>
  <option data-desc="Atla" value="#tiera">Atlanta</option>
  <option data-desc="Aust" value="#tierc">Austin</option>
  <option data-desc="Balt" value="#tiera">Baltimore</option>
  <option data-desc="Bost" value="#tierb">Boston</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var descriptions = {
    Atla: "info on Atlanta",
    Aust: "info on Austin",
    Balt: "info on Baltimore",
    Bost: "info on Boston"
}

$("#selectedCity").change(function() {
    var desc = descriptions[$("option:selected", this).data("desc")];
    $("p").text(desc);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4mtcu8md/